# Windows freezes when in game

Tags: windows-7, crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Freezes (No BSOD)](https://superuser.com/questions/66986/windows-7-freezes-no-bsod)

Recently when I have been playing or using relatively graphics intensive things like bad company 2, unreal development kit(test/run mode), or crysis2, windows will lock up during gameplay even though task manager is reporting average amounts of use. when it locks up I am unable to do anything and I end up having to force shut down. The first time this happened it was about thirty minutes in and each time since it has happened quicker. I am running windows 7 ultimate x64 on a 3 year old modified hp desktop. Every component seems to be working fine except for one fan that will occasionally make some noise. What could be causing these crashes/lockups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like CPU / GPU / RAM overheating - especially if you've a dodgy fan somewhere in your system.

Open up your system and ensure all air intakes, fans and heatsins are clear of contamination - use a can of air duster or similar to remove any contamination.

You might also want to apply a fresh layer of thermal paste between your CPU & HSF module.  Take care when doing this, and don't apply too much.

Replace the dodgy fan if you can - improper airflow won't usually cause lockups by itself, but it's best to sort this while you've got the case open anyway.

It's also possible you have a power supply problem, but I would expect that to manifest more quickly, and to show up during other non-gaming usage.

Comment: Hmm, I will have to check. My wireless card has also been acting up a bit lately. Speed fan is reporting temps ranging from 22 to 49. Most being around 40-42 C. One of the hard drives is at 42 and it is saying it is too hot.

Comment: I just ran lightwave and udk and the gpu, core, and other sections suddenly turned red and then it showed a little flame. I will check inside the case tommorow.

Comment: Turns out the fan on my graphics card was what was making the noise. All other fans seemed to be working fine, but when in the games everything started spiking, not just the gpu. Why is this just happening now?

Comment: With the machine being about 3 years old, this is almost expected.  When the GPU temperature spikes, it will push up the case temperature and lead to other components also spiking.  The fan is likely of the 'teflon bearing' type which have a limited operating life before the bearing wears.  Replace the fan if you can, and if possible with your card also replace the thermal compound between the heatsink and the GPU - that should buy you another year or two of working hardware (though you'll likely need to upgrade within that timeframe anyway).

Comment: I used the reverse end of a vacuum to blow out a bunch of dust. I turned it back on, now the gpu fan makes a different quieter noise(still not the original though) and speed fan is showing most temperatures lowered a bit. Except for one unlabeled temp that is 3 degrees more than it normally was.

Comment: Oop, most of the temps are back up to where they were before. I am going to try a game again.

Comment: Tried some stuff and the gpu temp shot up to the flame again.