# How can I prevent Windows Update from crashing my computer?

Tags: windows, crash, freeze, updates

I have Automatic Updates enabled and every now and then I'll get that little pop-up window that nags me to reboot to complete the update process.  Usually, I ignore it and after 2 days my computer crashes.  It crashes by freezing all the programs, including Windows Explorer, to the point that I can't even use CTRL-Alt-Delete (and my mouse lags).

I'm pretty sure it's Windows Updates that is causing this.  So, for now, I've disabled Windows Updates.

Comment: I agree that the nagging window is truly irritating, but are you certain it is related to the freezing? I have left it go for weeks and never had an issue. Does it happen every time you get that nagging window? What other applications do you keep open? What version of windows are you running?

Comment: It has happened every single time that little windows update window is there. I usually have chrome, foobar, and digsby opened. And I'm running Windows 7. Chrome might have something to do with triggering because every time it's happened it happened right after I opened a new tab.

Comment: I had almost some problem, the computer started to lag when updates begin to install. But i had broken HDD and after replace everything worked fine.

Comment: After two or three days, if your computer still freezes, then you'll know it's not caused by Windows Update (because you've disabled automatic Windows Updates).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 Freezes (No BSOD)](http://superuser.com/questions/66986/windows-7-freezes-no-bsod)

Comment: @Randolf yes we'll see

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to your question is this: reboot the computer. Or if it crashes during an update, just hold the power button for 10 seconds until it shuts down, then reboot. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to keep my computer on forever.

Comment: 'on forever' is probably not a good idea with Windows.

Comment: You may need to use an OS that has a known **track record of "extended periods for up time,"** such as Linux/Unix.

Comment: I do use linux on my other computer from programming related stuff. But I have windows on this because of a few windows only programs.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your hardware. Windows Updates NEVER cause those types of problems for me. Go to Start, type 'Memory Diagnostic' and select the program in the menu. Let it run and see if your RAM is OK. After that, check your hard drive with a program like HDTune, or even Windows' own CHKDSK. Click Start, type `cmd`, then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to run as Admin. Type `CHKDSK C: /f /r` and press Enter

Comment: Hardware is definitely the next logical suspect (+1), and bad sectors on the hard drive can definitely cause this sort of problem.

Comment: Memory Diagnostic returned no errors. And CHKDSK returned "0 KB in bad sectors"

Comment: Did CHKDSK show that it fixed any errors or issues in the partition table or security indexes? Do you have any found.xxx hidden folders on the root of the C:?

Comment: I closed the cmd window already. And I don't have any found.xxx files in C root.

Comment: In the Command Prompt, type `dir /a /d c:\found.???` and see if it finds any. If it does, then you had hard drive errors that were recovered. If not, then your HDD is probably fine

Comment: "File Not Found". So then it's not a hard drive problem.

Comment: You're right, it's not.